# How to get current date on load of a Lightning web component?

Tags: javascript

Can you please provide me the best solution?

Comment: Hello Manoj, Welcome to SFSE, what have you tried so far? Have you tried getting the value in client side and server side and tried to understand the difference?

Answer (score 3):

LWC is based on web technologies and uses JavaScript for writing the client-side logic. That means you have direct access to the client's understanding of current date/time using the JavaScript Date class, including [Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now).

The server side functionality (accessed via wired or imperatively called Apex) is written in Apex and provides access to the server's understanding of current date/time using the Apex class [System](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_system.htm) with the System.now() and System.today() functions. (There's also Date and Datetime access to this and related functionality.)

Both client and server will take timezone into account (though not necessarily the same one - it depends on how the User and browser are set) while it is also possible to use other, related features to get UTC values.

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as it can get.. Lightning web component follows the Standard JavaScript...

So to get the current date, you can use the standard Date class of JS.

EDIT: Convert JS time to “Unix Timestamp” (number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).

In Apex Code, you can use DateTime.newInstance(unixTimestamp) to return a DateTime that contains the formatted date/time value. Then use myDate.format() apex method to convert it in local timezone.

```
JS:
const date1 = new Date();
const unixTimeMilSec = date1.getTime();

// Tue Nov 26 2019 13:27:09 GMT...
console.log('date today..' + unixTimeMilSec);

Apex:
//newInstance will return dateTime in GMT, then format() will change it to local timezone
DateTime dt = DateTime.newInstance(unixTimeMilSec).format();
```

Hope it will help..

Comment: You didn't consider that there can be differences between server-side and client-side date/time values. Nor that timezones can come into play...

Comment: Convert JS time to “Unix Timestamp” (number of milliseconds since January 1st, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT). 

Example:
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getTime();

In Apex Code, you can use DateTime.newInstance(unixTimestamp) to return a DateTime that contains the formatted date/time value. 

In JavaScript, use new Date(unitTimestamp) to get the same result. To convert back, in Apex Code, use myDate.getTime(), and in JavaScript, use the same function: myDate.getTime().

Comment: Add that to your answer to improve it :)

Comment: Made the edits.. hope that will help.